# Bedeutung von „strohblond“

Tags: meaning

Beim Nachdenken ist mir zufällig das Wort *[strohblond](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strohblond)* in den Sinn gekommen.
Obwohl ich das Wort schon kenne, seit ich mich erinnern kann, wurde mir bewusst, dass mir die Bedeutung eigentlich gar nicht hundertprozentig klar ist.

> Johann ist **strohblond**. (Alternativ: Johann hat **strohblondes** Haar.)

Dieser Satz bedeutet logischerweise, dass ein gewisser Johann eine Form von blonden Haaren hat. Die exakte Bedeutung ist mir jedoch unklar, ich habe folgende Thesen dazu:

1. *Strohblond* bedeutet, dass die Haare ungefähr die gleiche Farbe aufweisen, wie es übliches Stroh tut.
2. *Strohblond* steht einfach für sehr helles, blondes Haar.

Ehrlich gesagt habe ich keine handfesten Indizien, die auf die zweite These schließen lassen, jedoch sagt mein Gefühl, dass eher die zweite als die erste These zutrifft, zumal es erstens Haare gibt, die viel heller als übliches Stroh sind, und des Weiteren hat Stroh meines Wissens nicht in jeder Phase ein und dieselbe Pigmentierung.

Trifft eine meiner Thesen zu oder was ist die genaue Bedeutung?

Comment: Wenn ich höre, dass jemand "strohblond" ist, denke ich erstmal, dass er sehr dumm sein muss. :p

Comment: Völlig ohne Bezug zum Thema: _Ich kenne das Wort schon, seit ich mich erinnern kann_ ist eine interessante Kontamination. :-)

Comment: @Em1 warum denn das? wegen strohdumm nehme ich an...? ;)

Comment: @WayneEra Nein, weil "blond = dumm" und "strohblond = sehr blond = sehr dumm"

Comment: @Em1 auch nachvollziehbar ^^

Comment: @Em1 Protest zum Zwecke des Selbstschutzes....!

Comment: @Stephie *lach* Ich habe selbst blondes Haar. Aber das blond mit dumm assoziiert wird, kann man nicht von der Hand weisen.

Comment: @Stephie aber dann 'gekontert' falsch schreiben - case in point? ;) (Bah, was red' ich, bin auch blond :D)

Comment: @Stephie Ich wollte eigentlich noch was mit "gekonntere Erklärung" schreiben, aber ausformuliert war einfach nix Schickes dabei ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Bedeutung von *Strohblond* in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/strohblond) lautet: „helles Haar ähnlich der Farbe von Stroh habend“ und eine [Friseurseite](http://www.vorher-nachher-frisuren.de/frisuren/strohblond/) schreibt weiter:

> Strohblond wird ein gelblicher, heller Blondton genannt, der vor allem bei Sommertypen eine Existenzgrundlage findet.

Ich selbst hätte Strohblond als helles Blond mit Goldstich beschrieben. Hier ein typisches Beispiel: [(Stroh-)Blond](http://fc-foto.de/20366942)

Comment: Ich kenne beispielsweise einen Norweger, der hat so blonde Haare (wie das in den skandinavischen Ländern häufiger auftritt), dass sie mit sicherheit heller sind als jedes Stroh. Würdes du das dann immernoch als strohblond bezeichnen?

Comment: @WayneEra, kommt drauf an. Hat es noch einen Gold-/Gelbstich? Dann eventuell ja. Bei sehr hellem Blond erscheint mir Strohblond aber nicht mehr passend, da würde ich ein neutrales "Hellblond" nehmen. Schimmert das Haar silbern, dann passt Strohblond auf jeden Fall nicht.

Comment: haha so genau habe ich seine haarfarbe auch nicht beobachtet. aber das beantwortet teilweise meine frage, ob das dann strohblond oder hellblond ist, also danke dafür :)

Comment: WayneEra Für extrem helle Haare kann man auch Weißblond sagen.... Das ist in echt zumindest in unseren Breiten so selten, dass man nicht unbedingt an den Begriff denkt.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn mir gegenüber jemand *strohblond* erwähnt, denke ich an hellblondes Haar.
[Der Online- Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strohblond) setzt *strohblond* mit *flachsblond* gleich und erklärt *flachsblond* mit *hellblond*.

Stroh ist normalerweise auch sehr hell (etwa aus [Weizen](https://www.google.at/search?q=weizen&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI2-LO96HxyAIVQ04UCh1Pkwp4&biw=1536&bih=721)) – das ist besonders gut erkennbar, wenn man einen einzelnen Halm hernimmt. In Ballen sieht es oft dünkler aus, da die Halme im Inneren überschattet werden. Außerdem darf man Stroh nicht mit Heu verwechseln.

Comment: den duden link hatte ich auch schon drin ^^ aber jedenfalls danke für die antwort

Comment: @WayneEra Siehe Edit.

Comment: alles klar, danke